# Spring Boot logging extensions to Logback not working

Tags: logging, spring-boot

According to the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html) Spring Boot should use `logback-spring.xml` to configure logging (allowing the use of properties), but a file of that name isn't picked up when my application starts.

I don't have logging explicity configured in my POM, but `spring-boot-starter-logging` v1.2.6 is pulled in via `spring-boot-starter-web`.

Any ideas why this? `logback.xml` is pulled in fine though.

Thanks

Nick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're reading the documentation for the yet-to-be-released Spring Boot 1.3, but you're using Spring Boot 1.2.6. Support for `logback-spring.xml` is [new in Spring Boot 1.3](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.3.0-M2-Release-Notes#logging) which is why it doesn't work with 1.2.6.

You might like to try the latest milestone of 1.3, 1.3.0.M5, which is available from https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone.